# PHP: Contact us form does not echo success text

Tags: php

I have two html forms that both send emails successfully using PHP. However, one form echo successful submission text, but the other one does not.

Here is the form that is part of the index.html page, which does not echo any text after submission. Please note, the email still sends:

```
<form class="booking-form" id="myForm" action="#">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column">
                                    <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Name'" class="form-control mt-20" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
                                    <input name="subject" placeholder="subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'subject'" class="form-control mt-20" required="" type="text">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
                                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'" class="form-control mt-20" required="" type="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 flex-column">
                                    <textarea rows="5" class="form-control mt-20" name="message" placeholder="Messege" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Messege'" required=""></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-end send-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" class="genric-btn primary mt-20 text-uppercase ">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

The following is the PHP mailer code:

```
    <?php

    $to = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
    $firstname = $_POST["name"];
    $email= $_POST["email"];
    $text= $_POST["message"];
    $subject= $_POST["subject"];



    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Email coming from Brave Towing " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style=\"background-color:#fafafa;\">
        <div style=\"padding:20px;\">
            Customer Email: <span style=\"color:#888\">$email</span>
            <br>
            Contact Subject: <span style=\"color:#888\">$subject</span>
            <br>
            Contact Message: <div style=\"color:#888\">$text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
";

    if (@mail($to, $email, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo '<h1>The message has been sent</h1>';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your `@mail` is suppressing the error message, which may hold useful information.

Comment: I do not think so because the form submits fine...

Comment: try without `@` and tell us the output

Comment: When I remove @ the form still submits and email is sent and received, but I do not got the echo on the form?

Comment: Basically what is going on, I have the same contact us form on two different pages. One page is contact.html => this page works fine, when I submit the form I get the echo text just fine. However, there is the same form with the same action name and such on index.html ==> when I submit the form from this page, the email sends, but does not echo anything. If this helps...